# RedisBloom: Option to add items (bit strings) as is with no hashing?

Tags: redis, bloom-filter

I'm considering redis for my next project (in-memory, fast) but now I have the problem of figuring out how and if at all it could actually achieve my goal. The goal is to store "large" (millions) amount of fixed-length bit strings and then searching over the database with a input (query) bit string. Search means to return everything which fulfills below condition:

query & value = query

eg. if all bits set in the query are also set in the value return that key eg. bloom-filter albeit in my domain of work it isn't usually called like that.

I found the module [RedisBloom](https://github.com/RedisBloom/RedisBloom) but I already have my bloom filter (bit strings) available from external program and would simply like to use RedisBloom for storage of them and searching (exists command). therefore in my case the "Add" command should take the input as is and not hash it again.

Is that possible? And if not other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that isn't possible as RedisBloom is a "black box" in that sense - it manages its own data structures.